# What species is Angela?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

In the book *Eragon*, what species is Angela? I am confused because she looks like a human not an elf, but she is super old.

**Is she a different species?**

Comment: The wiki says that it isn't clear; http://inheritance.wikia.com/wiki/Angela

Comment: .....Time Lord.

Answer (score 4):

In Brisingr, Arya stated "If we judge by years and not wisdom, no human would be considered an adult among my kind. Except Galbatorix." Angela says she is human when she said in response "And me".

Answer (score 1):

[Angela](http://inheritance.wikia.com/wiki/Angela) is presumed to be Human, but this is never explicitly confirmed. It is possible she is one of the [Grey Folk](http://inheritance.wikia.com/wiki/Grey_Folk).

Paolini has left this character deliberately vague for some reason we will probably discover in Book 5.

> Well, since you asked nicely — Book V will feature Angela’s backstory quite prominently.
>   <sub>[paolini.net](https://www.paolini.net/2016/01/27/q-and-a-with-christopher-book-5s-plot-why-arya-became-queen-and-galbatorixs-demise/)</sub>

Comment: I thought the cycle was already finished? Is there still a book coming?

Comment: The Cycle is done. But "someday" we will get a sequel that is only known as *Book V* right now.